# How to fill part of the background with gradient color?

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I'd like to have `div` with color filled background:

- linear gradient from left to right
- filling only 20% from the bottom of the `div`.

  .my-div {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #FFEBEE);
  }

How to define second condition?

https://jsfiddle.net/tf4nn5p6/

Comment: post the code what you have tried

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tf4nn5p6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```css
.my-div{
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #FFEBEE);
  background-size: 100% 20%;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='my-div'>
 text
</div>
```

Comment: background-repeat: no-repeat; - that's that I didn't apply in my tryings! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What I was loooking for

Answer (score 0):

Use below css for the same and here you can control by **background-size: 100% 20%;** and **background-position: left bottom;** with no-repeat

```
.my-div{
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #FFEBEE);
  background-size: 100% 20%;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```